# PyCharm complaining about parentheses in a python function call

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pycharm

Running Jetbrain PyCharm 2021.3 on Windows with Python 3.7.9 (64-bit) installed.
The code is simple:
`homedir=os.path.expanduser('~')`

Here is a picure in the IDE line 32:
[image: Code as seen in IDE]

[image: Error List detailing errors in code]

Have anyone seen this type of parsing error?  Is this unique to Windows, Python version installed or Jetbrain Issue?  Any clue will be helpful.

Comment: Is your file a shell script or a python file? It looks like python but the extension `.sh` is likely telling pycharm to parse it as a shell script.

Comment: You are right.  The file was started as a bash script then they decided to use python and just set the [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) in the file.  @JonSG is you write an answer I was upvote and an accept it. I am guessing PyCharm does not  recognize the [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice from the screenshot that the file you are editing with python has an extension of `.sh`. I think that the extension is being used by pycharm to determine how to parse the file and it is getting confused. I recommend you try switching the extension to `.py`.

Comment: I am glad I uploaded that screen shot. I would have been racking by brain for a couple of hours

Comment: Ya, I no screenshots are frowned upon, but without it I would never have noticed the extension mis-match :-)